# Can SquirrelMail read and send emails using MS Exchange

Tags: exchange-2010, squirrelmail

Can SquirrelMail read and send emails using MS Exchange? I have one Windows box that is not connected to internet (it's only connected to intranet), and one more machine connected to internet with Ubuntu Linux on it, with installed SquirrelMail as webmail client.

It is possible to have this combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If squirrel mail is already installed, then run the conf.pl script to configure it. Look for the Server Settings option in ***Menu => Update IMAP Settings***. Point it to correct MS Exchange server IMAP IP or domain name as well as smtp server (it can be MS Exchange or sendmail/qmail etc).

The conf.pl is located at /usr/share/squirrelmail/config directory in Red hat and I believe under /etc/squirrelmail directory under Debian.

You could also check the [FAQ section](http://squirrelmail.org/wiki/SquirrelMailWithExchangeFAQ) in Squirrelmail's website for some possible answers.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Admission:  I haven't tried this myself.

However.

SquirrelMail supports IMAP and SMTP.  If your Exchange server supports IMAP, then yes.  You'll also need to enable some kind of authentication for SMTP that SquirrelMail supports.  I would also recommend that you set them both up to go over SSL.

IMAP:
http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-enable-imap-access-to-exchange-mailboxes.htm
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2573225

SMTP:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2006/12/28/3397620.aspx
http://www.petri.co.il/authenticated-or-anonymous-smtp-relay-with-exchange-2007.htm

Out of the box, the answer is no.  Exchange doesn't do this by default.